# How to establish a web3 provider connection from a Vue.js DApp?

Tags: vue.js, metamask, ethers.js, rsk

I am intended to interact with [Rootstock](https://developers.rsk.co/) blockchain
from a `vue.js` DApp to track wallet balance and send  RBTC.
​
I want to establish a [Metamask](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/) connection
and use [ethers.js web3 provider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/other/#Web3Provider)
to interact with the Rootstock network.
​
I created a [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) storage
to keep all the web3 data available for the whole app.
Here is a concise version of what I've done so far:
​

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { providers } from 'ethers';
​
export const useRootstockStore = defineStore('rootstock', () => {
  const balance = ref(0);
  const address = ref('');
  const provider = ref(null);
​
  const getBalance = async () => {
    balance.value = await provider.value.getBalance(address.value);
  };
​
  const connect = async () => {
    await window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
    });
    provider.value = new providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    [address.value] = await provider.value.listAccounts();
  };
​
...
});
```

​
Within the storage I have:
​

- `provider` ref which is supposed to store a reference to web3 provider
- `address` ref keeping the Metamask wallet address
- `balance` ref storing the wallet balance
- `connect` function which establishes Metamask connection and instantiates ethers web3 provider
- `getBalance` function which queries the provider for RBTC balance of the wallet
  ​
  After calling the `connect` function,
  the app connects to Metamask and
  seems to establish a connection with Rootstock,
  however when I try to query the wallet's RBTC balance,
  I keep getting the following error:
  ​

```
TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property '_network' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value (expected '#<Object>' but got '#<Object>')
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (base-provider.ts:820:22)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (formatter.ts:523:1)
```

​
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Swap out [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref),
and replace it with
[`computed`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed).

Instead of using a `ref` to store the provider:

```js
const provider = ref(null);
```

you should use `computed` to store the provider instead:

```js
const provider = computed(() => new providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum));
```

So, the whole script should be as follows:

```js
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
...
export const useRootstockStore = defineStore('rootstock', () => {
  const balance = ref(0);
  const address = ref('');
  const provider = computed(() => new providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum));

  const getBalance = async () => {
    balance.value = await provider.value.getBalance(address.value);
  };

  const connect = async () => {
    await window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
    });
    [address.value] = await provider.value.listAccounts();
  };
...
});
```

This should resolve your issue.